# Aumentar imagen en Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin

Estoy haciendo una app con xamarin forms y en un content page muestro una imagen, alguien sabe como puedo hacer para que al hacer clic en la imagen, se agrande y se pueda acercar la imagen, ya que la imagen es un mapa y tiene información que no se ve a simple vista, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La mejor manera es asi:

```
    private void OnTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Content.Scale > MIN_SCALE)
        {
            RestoreScaleValues();
        }
        else
        {
            Content.AnchorX = Content.AnchorY = 0.5;
            Content.ScaleTo(MAX_SCALE, 250, Easing.CubicInOut);             
        }
    }


    void RestoreScaleValues()
    {
        Content.ScaleTo(MIN_SCALE, 250, Easing.CubicInOut);
        Content.TranslateTo(0.5, 0.5, 250, Easing.CubicInOut);

        currentScale = 1;

        Content.TranslationX = 0.5;
        Content.TranslationY = 0.5;

        xOffset = Content.TranslationX;
        yOffset = Content.TranslationY;
    }
```